# How to access local files in Spark on Windows?

Tags: windows, scala, apache-spark

I am using `Spark` on `Windows`. I know in `*nix`, accessing local file code likes this:

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/README.md")
```

But how can I access a local file on `Windows`? I have tried following methods:

```
val logFile = "C:\spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.4\README.md"
val logFile = "file\\C:\spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.4\README.md"
```

But all can't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately in windows you have to escape `"\"`.

Try:

```
"C:\\spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.4\\README.md"
```

Comment: Cool! You are right! It should be "`val logFile = "C:\\spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.4\\README.md"`".

Comment: I am trying to configure below path as spark streaming source. Not working andy clue? new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "\\data"

Answer (score 2):

It should work with below code. Else try checking for spelling and correct path.

```
val path = "C:\\spark_home\\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\\README.md"
val read = sc.textFile(path)
```

Answer (score 2):

In windows you have to specify as follows:

```
"file///C:/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.4/README.md"
```

Comment: I write as you suggested and I get AnalysisException: 'Path does not exist: file:/server444/files/randomtest.csv

Comment: It should be `"file:///c:/xx/xx.txt"`. You are missing `:`.

Answer (score 1):

**For CSV and txt file dont specify the format**,

```
val file = "C:\\Users\\testUser\\IdeaProjects\\SparkDataQualityReporting\\SampleData"
val fileRDD = sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows, we can specify as:

```
spark.read.format("json").load("file:///C:/workspace/sample_data.json")
```