# Why does Spark report "java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI" when working with DataFrames?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am running Spark locally on a Windows machine. I was able to launch the spark shell successfully and also read in text files as RDDs. I was also able to follow along the various online tutorials on this subject and was able to perform various operations on the RDDs.

However, when I try to convert an RDD into a DataFrame I am getting an error. This is what I am doing:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

//convert rdd to df
val df = rddFile.toDF()
```

This code generates a long series of error messages that seem to relate to the following one:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:C:/Users/spark/spark-warehouse
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getWhRoot(Warehouse.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getDefaultDatabasePath(Warehouse.java:177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB_core(HiveMetaStore.java:600)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:620)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
        ... 85 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:C:/Users/spark/spark-warehouse
        at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1823)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:745)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:202)
        ... 96 more
```

The entire stack trace follows.

```
16/08/16 12:36:20 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
16/08/16 12:36:20 WARN Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:171)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:258)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:359)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive(HiveSharedState.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog(HiveSharedState.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.catalog(HiveSessionState.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionState.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(HiveSessionState.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.analyzer(HiveSessionState.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.baseRelationToDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:382)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:401)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:342)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:24)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:29)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:31)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:33)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:35)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:37)
        at $line14.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:39)
        at $line14.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:41)
        at $line14.$read.<init>(<console>:43)
        at $line14.$read$.<init>(<console>:47)
        at $line14.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line14.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line14.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line14.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:415)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:923)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1234)
        ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
        ... 80 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:C:/Users/spark/spark-warehouse
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getWhRoot(Warehouse.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.Warehouse.getDefaultDatabasePath(Warehouse.java:177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB_core(HiveMetaStore.java:600)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:620)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
        ... 85 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:C:/Users/spark/spark-warehouse
        at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1823)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:745)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:202)
        ... 96 more
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's the [SPARK-15565 issue in Spark 2.0 on Windows](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15565) with a simple solution (that appears to be [part of Spark's codebase](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/c17272902c95290beca274ee6316a8a98fd7a725) that may soon be released as 2.0.2 or 2.1.0).

The solution in Spark 2.0.0 is to set `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` to some properly-referenced directory, say `file:///c:/Spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-warehouse` that uses `///` (triple slashes).

Start `spark-shell` with `--conf` argument as follows:

```
spark-shell --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=file:///c:/tmp/spark-warehouse
```

Or create a `SparkSession` in your Spark application using the new fluent builder pattern as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///c:/tmp/spark-warehouse")
  .getOrCreate()
```

Or create `conf/spark-defaults.conf` with the following content:

```
spark.sql.warehouse.dir file:///c:/tmp/spark-warehouse
```

Comment: this problem still appears to me at Spark 2.2.0 but I'm using google cloud storage so I have a path like this gs://prefix:remaining what should I do to fix this problem. I can't remove the middle colon. I can't control it?

Comment: Please ask a separate question since it's GCS-specific. I truly don't know the answer.

Answer (score 8):

I also got this error. In my case I was writting a file with the character ":" in the name ex: `/tmp/dattaset_10:23:11`. Then spark gets confused because thinks the `:` is part of a path (like `C:\`).

**The solution is just to remove the `:` character from the file name**

Comment: In case I want to read the file instead of writing it, can I escape the path so Spark can read it?

Answer (score 4):

If you do want to fix it in code yet not touch exsiting code, can also pass it from system properties, such that the spark initializations which comes after won't change.

```
System.setProperty(
    "spark.sql.warehouse.dir", 
    s"file:///${System.getProperty("user.dir")}/spark-warehouse"
    .replaceAll("\\\\", "/")
)
```

Note, also this is using the current working dir, which can be replaced with "c:/tmp/", or any place you'd like the spark-warehouse dir.

Answer (score 0):

Just set config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///tmp/spark-warehouse").

No need to include **"C:/"**.

Spark driver will automatically create folder under the /tmp/spark-warehouse directory. If it's windows, it will be under **"C:/"**. The **"C:"** drive will not work if the master is not local on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I set spark.sql.warehouse.dir property to fix the error in my existing code

```
System.setProperty("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/spark-warehouse");
```

Here is the code snippet

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "c:/winutil/");
System.setProperty("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/spark-warehouse");
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[*]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val lines = sc.textFile("C:/user.txt")
```